# Use flynn applications via single domain

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, flynn

In order to have less issues with CORS and be able to use one SSL cert, I would like to run all flynn applications with one domain:

my "external" services

- https://example.com/ - Frontend SPA (static, HTML/javascript)
- https://example.com/api/v1/* - API (Python/Django)
- https://example.com/admin/ - Django Admin
- https://example.com/docs/ - SwaggerUI (static, HTML/Javascript)
- https://example.com/static/ - All static files from user uploads

internal services

- redis
- postgres

$ flynn route (example)

```
http:api.service.example.com        api
http:frontend.service.example.com   frontend
http:docs.service.example.com       docs
...
```

To keep things simple, my idea was to use the NGINX as a reverse proxy to take care of the routing and the SSL handling - but where should I put it?

I could add an NGINX as a flynn application that listens to example.com and then make use of `location` and `proxy_pass` features. But when the NGINX reverses from https://example.com to http://frontend.service.example.com I have no SSL here - is that right?

How to make sure, the NGINX routes only "internally"? Are there even better approaches with flynn - or just use dokku.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Flynn using built-in features, there is no need to use an external reverse proxy.

First, add `example.com` with a valid TLS certificate:

```
flynn -a frontend route add http example.com --tls-cert cert_chain.pem --tls-key cert_key.pem
```

The `cert_chain.pem` file should contain the PEM-encoded certificate followed by one or more intermediate certificates necessary to build the chain to a trusted root.

The `cert_key.pem` file should contain a PEM-encoded private key (with no encryption applied).

Then add a path-based route for each of your other apps. The path will be treated as a prefix, so all subpaths will match as well for the route and the TLS certificate you just added will be used for all of them because they have the same domain:

```
flynn -a api route add http example.com/api
flynn -a admin route add http example.com/admin
flynn -a docs route add http example.com/docs
flynn -a static route add http example.com/static
```

The first route with just the base domain will be used for all other paths.